# Mapping higher dimensions to color, opacity, point size, etc

Tags: plotting

I have a set of points of dimension >3, and I'd like to modify ListPointPlot3D so that the higher dimensions are mapped to different variables, such as color, opacity, point size, etc. so for example

```
a = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3], 4], {5000}];
ListPointPlot3D[a] +some options...
```

Comment: High dimensional data visualization is a very hot research topic nowadays.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
t1 = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3], 4], {500}];  
min = Min[t1[[;; , 4]]];
max = Max[t1[[;; , 4]]];
ps = {PointSize[1/30 (# - min)/(max - min)], 
 Hue[(# - min)/(max - min)], Opacity[(# - min)/(max - min)]} & /@t1[[;; , 4]];
Show[ListPointPlot3D[{t1[[;; , 1 ;; 3]][[#]]},PlotStyle -> {Evaluate[ps[[#]]]}] & /@ Range[Length[ps]]]
```

[image: varying options for the plot using the fourth dimension]

You can do it as a single plot (rather than a table) and it would be faster but this was the easiest way I found to do it.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a built-in function named `Rescale[]`?

Comment: I wasn't, thank you. Normally I don't expect such simple functions to be available so it's nice when they are.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another example. This is a plotting routine that I used recently. It is very customized to my application, but gives you another idea how to visualize n-dim data. Each data point depends on three model parameters {n,M,$\chi$}. I encode the parameter values as symbol size, symbol shape and symbol color. (The parameter values take fixed values and do not change continously).

```
filledsymbols = {"\[FilledCircle]", "\[FilledSquare]", 
                 "\[FilledDiamond]", "\[FilledRectangle]", "\[FilledDownTriangle]", 
                 "\[FilledUpTriangle]", "\[FilledRightTriangle]"};
emptysymbols = {"\[RightTriangle]", "\[EmptyCircle]", 
                "\[EmptySquare]", "\[EmptyDiamond]", "\[EmptyRectangle]", 
                "\[EmptyDownTriangle]", "\[EmptyUpTriangle]"};
symbolcolors = {Black, Gray, Blue, Red, Green, Orange, Cyan};
symbolsizes = {9, 12, 17, 22, 25};
marker[nstring_, Mstring_, \[Chi]string_] := Module[{m1, m2, m3},
            m1 = Switch[nstring, 
                         "30", symbolsizes[[1]], 
                         "40", symbolsizes[[2]],
                         "50", symbolsizes[[3]], 
                         "60", symbolsizes[[4]], 
                         "70", symbolsizes[[5]]
                       ];
            m2 = Switch[Mstring, 
                         "-30", filledsymbols[[1]], 
                         "-20", filledsymbols[[2]], 
                         "-10", filledsymbols[[3]], 
                         "00",  filledsymbols[[4]], 
                         "10",  filledsymbols[[5]], 
                         "20",  filledsymbols[[6]], 
                         "30",  filledsymbols[[7]]
                       ];
                 {m2, m1}]
 style[\[Chi]string_] := Module[{m1, m2, m3},
            m3 = Switch[\[Chi]string, 
                         "00", symbolcolors[[1]], 
                         "10", symbolcolors[[2]], 
                         "20", symbolcolors[[3]], 
                         "30", symbolcolors[[4]], 
                         "40", symbolcolors[[5]], 
                         "50", symbolcolors[[6]], 
                          "60", symbolcolors[[7]]
                       ];
        {m3}]
```

And here the plotting function.

```
Options[generalRatioPlot] = {ShowLegend -> True};
generalRatioPlot::wlen = "Data and parameter array have different length.";
generalRatioPlot[data_, parameter_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{plt, legendAll, showleg},
      showleg = ShowLegend /. {opts} /. Options[generalRatioPlot];
      If[Length[parameter] =!= Length[data],Message[generalRatioPlot::wlen]; Abort[]];
      legendAll = Flatten[{
                    Table[{Item[Style["\[FilledSquare]", Evaluate@symbolsizes[[i]]],
                                Alignment -> Left], 
                           Item[Style[{"n=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)", 
                                       "n=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 
                                       "n=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 
                                       "n=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\)", 
                                       "n=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(7\)]\)"}[[i]], 
                                FontFamily -> "Times"], Alignment -> Left]}, {i, 1, 5}],
                    Table[{emptysymbols[[i]], 
                           Item[Style[{"M=0.001", "M=0.01", "M=0.1", "M=1", "M=10", 
                                       "M=100", "M=1000"}[[i]], FontFamily -> "Times"], 
                                Alignment -> Left]}, {i, 1, 7}], 
                    Table[{Style["\[FilledSquare]", symbolcolors[[i]]], 
                        Item[Style[{"\[Chi]=1", "\[Chi]=10", 
                                    "\[Chi]=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(2\)]\)", 
                                    "\[Chi]=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(3\)]\)", 
                                    "\[Chi]=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)", 
                                    "\[Chi]=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(5\)]\)", 
                                    "\[Chi]=\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(6\)]\)"}[[i]], 
                             FontFamily -> "Times"], Alignment -> Left]}, {i, 1, 7}]
               }, 1];
 plt = ListLogLogPlot[Partition[data, 1], 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListLogLogPlot]]], 
    PlotMarkers -> marker /@ parameter[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
    PlotStyle -> style /@ parameter[[All, 3]], Frame -> True];
 If[showleg, Graphics[{
    Inset[Framed[Grid[legendAll], FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[0.5]], 
     Offset[{0, 0}, {1, 1}], {Right, Top}],
    Inset[Show[plt], Offset[{0, 4}, {-1, 1}], {Left, Top}, {1.7, 1.95}]}, 
  PlotRange -> 1., AspectRatio -> (1/GoldenRatio*0.88), ImageSize -> 600],
Show[plt, AspectRatio -> (1/GoldenRatio*0.88), ImageSize -> 600]]
];
```

And here a brief example:

```
data = Uncompress["1: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"];
pars = Uncompress["1:eJyNVcsOwjAMm4Af4QOQsjZtf4IT+wMOkzhxGP8vxjSkenLTXNY9rMSx3e76fD/mMAzDclkv99fymc/103Rab7JMv5e3UbbHIBzzW3aIMEj5f9uWxCAJICODRGhkVQkGlwyNKASrUC4FIMogCnRzo9EmbzBGijsmGnXQAovNPnY0ZhoNSMQ8UMxhKEq49LVRl5U1Gys0FhnMFa1y6OQxqsWmy1hRv1b8uhrj5HTrKtJpZbSqRh1XgND4JcdQ6hC5CFrW94oyzv0dnl3BqYdydLIgYsiXHYdABGkcXraO6rqThw2NFhpleSnug836/Vg/jnQQ+Avpbu+P"];    

generalRatioPlot[data, pars, 
                    ShowLegend -> True, 
                    PlotRange -> {{1 10^17, 3 10^18}, {65, 80}}, 
                    FrameTicks -> {{{50, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 90, 100, 110}, {}}, 
                     {{{10^17,"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(17\)]\)"}, 
                       {10^18,"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(18\)]\)"}, 
                       {2 10^17, ""}, {2 10^18, ""}, {3 10^17, ""}, 
                       {3 10^18, ""}, {4 10^17, ""}, 
                       {5 10^17, "5\[Cross]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(17\)]\)"},
                       {6 10^17, ""}, {7 10^17, ""}, 
                       {8 10^17, ""}, {9 10^17, ""}}, {}}}]
```

[image]